# Filling up a symmetric matrix and finding an expression in a fastest possible way

Tags: r, performance, matrix, vector, vectorization

I have a `n x n` symmetric matrix `G`, whose `(i,j)th` element is `g(h(i),h(j))`, with `g(i,j) = g(j,i)` and `g(i,i)` is constant for all `i`. Here `g` takes values in real line. In my case, say, `g` is the Gaussian kernel.

I have tried to input the matrix as follows.

```
h = 0.01
operator = function(x,y){
  return(dnorm((x-y)/h))
}

a = 1; b = 0.5; n = 20000
x = seq(1,n,1)
vec = a*x + b*x^2 #example of h(x)
G = outer(vec, vec, FUN = operator)
```

But, here I am calculating all the entries of the matrix, which is not necessary. Only lower triangular matrix and only one element of the diagonal should suffice. What can I do to implement that? (I think using `ifelse` makes the code slow.)

Then I want to do the following for some two `n x 1` vectors `a` and `b`

```
a = rnorm(n); b = rcauchy(n)
s = rowSums(G)
sum(((a/s) * (G %*% (b/a)))^2)
```

I know that using multi-cores with `parallel` makes code faster. But I do not know how to use that in my setting. Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

N.B. There are some suggestions in the comment section. Those, of course, makes the code faster and thus I really appreciate those. But I am looking for a way which can make this whole piece of code even faster, if possible.

Comment: Can you share a sample `g`? Is `g` vectorized?

Comment: `g` is a function taking values in the real line.  I have provided an example of that. Thanks for your comment, @Gregor!

Comment: Thanks for the `dnorm` example---is your real function vectorized similarly? With `dnorm`, for example, we could do `operator(x, x[1])` to get the first column of the  matrix all at once, so we could use a `for` loop (or a parallelized `foreach`, even) to do something like `for(i in 1:n) result[i:n, i] = operator(x[i:n], x[i])` quite efficiently. Is your real operator similarly vectorized?

Comment: Yes, my real operator is similarly vectorized. Thanks!

Comment: @Shanks I assume `operator` is not your real function? maybe you could provide your real one?

Comment: @Shanks why exactly ~0.005?

Comment: @minem, `operator` can be assumed as my real function. It is essentially any kernel function in my problem, so, alternatively you can also consider Epanechnikov kernel. This is a part from a chunk of codes, I calculated that if this piece of code runs in around 0.005 seconds, the whole process (optimization) will run within a few hours. Thank you very much for your comments!

Comment: However, you can just provide the fastest possible way that you can think of. I will anyway appreciate that, @minem.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but your expectations seems quite unrealistic.
To calculate 20k*20k matrix lower part, we need to calculate (n*n-n)/2 = 199990000 values.
But,

```
system.time(dnorm((x-y)/h)) # 12.47
```

This most simple computation on my system for such a length random vectors take ~12 sek.
But we still need to create the large symmetric matrix. So I do not see how this could be computed in ~0.005 sec (using R).

From my current testing, your approach seems like the fastest way to do it in R.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have three comments. 1)If `x` and `y` are different, it takes around 0.04 sec in my case. I expected 0.005 sec based on this observation. It is okay if it takes a little more time in your system. You just provide the fastest way you can come up with, as I have asked in my question. 2)In my case, `x=y`, so you don't have to calculate all elements, as `dnorm(a-b)=dnorm(b-a)` and also `dnorm(0)` is needed to be calculated once. 3)U can use the package `parallel` in some way, which I can not think of, to use different cores. I heard that makes code significantly faster.

Comment: @Shanks Sorry, but it seems that you do not see the point I am arising. `x` and `y` for this (my) calculation are vectors of length 199990000.That represents the unit count for which you need to compute the values (only lower triangular part, as for full matrix it would be 400 million). As this operation takes 12 sek for me, i do not see how it could be reduced to 0.005 sek for your simulations. Or did I misunderstood something?